# Get multiple and different input/select box values with jquery to submit with .ajax() in array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that gets generated dynamic every time with PHP and also gets updated with jQuery .appendTo() while the visitor interacts with it. The problem I have is that I want to get every single value of input text and select boxes from the current form and submit them with POST in arrays.
So far I have done the following (an example):

```
   <div>
        <input type="text" class="dynamicTags" name="dynamicTags1" value="Web Design"/>
        <select class="val_tag" name="val_tag1">                                               
               <option value="1" >Newbie</option>
               <option value="2" >Amateur</option>
               <option value="3" selected="selected" >Rockstar</option>
        </select>
    </div>                            
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="dynamicTags" name="dynamicTags2" value="Programming"/>
        <select class="val_tag" name="val_tag2">                                               
               <option value="1" >Newbie</option>
               <option value="2" selected="selected" >Amateur</option>
               <option value="3" >Rockstar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="dynamicTags" name="dynamicTags6" value="Java"/>
        <select class="val_tag" name="val_tag6">                                               
               <option value="1" >Newbie</option>
               <option value="2" >Amateur</option>
               <option value="3" selected="selected" >Rockstar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="dynamicTags" name="dynamicTags13" value="Photoshop"/>
        <select class="val_tag" name="val_tag13">                                               
               <option value="1" >Newbie</option>
               <option value="2" selected="selected" >Amateur</option>
               <option value="3" >Rockstar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

The name of each input text and select box is generated dynamic. The classes are the same.
With jQuery I managed to pass to my script simple variables from textboxes and select boxes (that I know from before) but I can't get to make it work with **arrays**. I have tried

```
data: {valTags: $('.val_tag').val(), dynTags: $('.dynamicTags').val()}
```

inside the $.ajax() function but without any luck. Sure I'm missing something crucial here but I can't find the proper way to do it. Do I have to use .each() function somehow?

In the end I would like to have in my **$_POST variable two arrays** like that:

```
dynamicTags[] = ([0] => 'Web Design', [1] => 'Programming', [2] => 'Java' ...etc....)

val_tag[] = ([0] => 1, [1] => 0, [2] => 0 ...etc....)
```

Comment: why do you not use the `.serialize()` function?

Comment: jQuery's getter methods (such as `.val()`) only return content from the first element. If you want an array, you'll have to use `.map().get()` or `$.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried your data as

```
 Data: serialize( $('#formID') ),
```

It would send all your form values in the post array which php can json_decode and iterate through as needed